# Passing RSS feeds to django view using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, rss

I'm pretty new to ajax.Following is my use case :
I am developing a side project that will show news and scores of different sports. For performing same, I am using rss feeds from different sources. I am able to fetch and parse the rss feeds in django views using 'feedparser' plugin, and passing the same as context to the corresponding template. Following is my view function and template(for cricket).

```
def cricket(request):
    feeds_cric = feedparser.parse('http://www.espncricinfo.com/rss/content/story/feeds/0.xml') #espncricinfo feed.
    feeds_cric_scores = feedparser.parse('http://static.cricinfo.com/rss/livescores.xml') #espncricinfo feed.
    context = {'feeds_cric': feeds_cric,'feeds_cric_scores' : feeds_cric_scores}
    return render(request,'scorecenter/cricket.html', context)
```

Following is the corresponding template.

```
{% extends "scorecenter/index.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <ul>
        {% for entry in feeds_cric.entries %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.link }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        <p>{{ entry.description }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

{% endblock content %}

{% block score %}
    <ul>
        {% for entry in feeds_cric_scores.entries %}
        <li><a href="{{ entry.link }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
        <!-- <p>{{ entry.description }}</p> -->
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endblock score %}
```

Following is index.html file.

Now, I want to use AJAX to reload only certain blocks of my page, rather than reloading and redirecting the complete page. I have written a script to check the

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Allscores</a>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="urlChecker('cricket')">Cricket</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="urlChecker('football')">Football</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="urlChecker('basketball')">Basketball</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" onclick="urlChecker('tennis')">Tennis</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default" id="empty_nav"></div>

    <div class="testingData">This should be updated</div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-8" id="news">

            <h3>Latest News</h3>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}

        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" id="scores">

            <h3>Latest scores</h3>
            {% block score %}
            {% endblock score %}

        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        Copyright © acllscores.com
    </div>
</body>
```

In my urlChecker() script, I check which anchor tag is clicked and assign the corresponding url. Following is the script :

```
function urlChecker (route) {
    switch(route) {
        case 'cricket':
            $.post( "/scorecenter/cricket/", function( data ) {
                $( ".result" ).html( data );
            });
            break;
        case 'football':
            $.post( "/scorecenter/football/", function( data ) {
                $( ".testingData" ).html( data );
            });
            break;
        case 'tennis':
            $.post( "/scorecenter/tennis/", function( data ) {
                $( ".testingData" ).html( data );
            });
            break;
        case 'basketball':
            $.post( "/scorecenter/basketball/", function( data ) {
                $( ".testingData" ).html( data );
            });
            break;

    }
}
```

Update : 
Adding urls file :

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'),
    url(r'^test/$', views.test,name='test'),

    url(r'^cricket/$', views.cricket,name='cricket'),
    url(r'^basketball/$', views.basketball,name='basketball'),
    url(r'^football/$', views.football,name='football'),
    url(r'^tennis/$', views.tennis,name='tennis'),

)
```

I am not fathom how to post the feed data to my templates using ajax. 
Please help

Comment: Do you have actual enpoints at the URLs you are posting to (e.g. `/scorecenter/basketball/`)?. If so, what do they look like? Also the text above the sample for the `index.html` seems cut at "... to check the ...". What errors do you currently get?

Comment: hi, yes i have endpoints to the URLs. Question updated with the contents of urls.py file. Currently what I was able to understand by debugging, my view function is not returning any data to ajax call, the request to the url 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/scorecenter/cricket/' is stuck in pending state.

Comment: Just saw your updated comment. If your endpoint views work by opening them directly through their url, next check the browser's development tools for which status code the ajax request returns. I've written a few points in the answer below that may be relevant to the question.

Answer (score 1):

**From the Ajax point of view**

From what you write in the question it would be more appropriate to send a `GET` request rather than a `POST` request. You are not sending any information to these endpoints that they need to store, but only want to *retrieve* updates from them. This doesn't change much of your code, you can do that with [☞ `$.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/) instead of `$.post()`.

---

**From the Django point of view**

Sending a `GET` request is also easier, since you don't need to account for [☞ Django's CSRF protection](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/csrf/). Issuing other ajax requests (like `POST`, `DELETE`, etc.) isn't all that hard either, but it requires an extra step that involves sending the CSRF token with every request (well documented in the linked docs).

---

**Rendering the result from the Ajax request**

Currently there might be a conceptual problem with the template that you use to render the Ajax results, e.g. `scorecenter/cricket.html`. On the very top you are extending from `index.html`, which means that each request will not only return the block of html that you want to insert but also anything that's part of `index.html`.

Also, since you will insert the results by Javascript into the already loaded website you don't need to define template blocks. Let these templates only render exactly the html that you want to insert into the DOM with `$('.testingData').html(data)`.

---

**Debugging problems with Ajax requests**

While developing your site, open the developer tools in your browser and activate the console there (either Firefox and Chrome are fine). Whenever an Ajax-request fails, it will display an error there, which you can then introspect.

Common errors are `404` (if the endpoint couldn't be found), `400` or `403` if the request was not authorized or `500` if the server has an error processing your request. [☞ More complete list of status codes](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmessages.asp)

Feel free to update your question with more details. Since this is a very wide topic be prepared that it might be closed by the community. In that case you can always search for more specific questions or if you don't find answers, put them in a new question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed and extremely informative reply. I am using get() method now. Working on loading of the templates and passing the feed objects from my view function, getting a 500 error as of now. Will update if not able to resolve the error.